# Disabling mute function on Cisco 7940 phone

Tags: phone

Is it possible to disable the mute function on a Cisco 7940? I can disable speakerphone and headset in Call Manager (4.1) but see no such option for the mute function.

We have a call center and apparently the operators are using the mute button to avoid making actual, you know, calls. They also use it to mask inappropriate conversations while on a call.

My suggestion to raise hiring standards was echoed by crickets.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is NOT possible on any version of CCM, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to set the Death Ray Zorcher to Shake-n-Bake.